# How can I get the total or sum up my database access

Tags: vb.net

i have this code which filter and display the database to datagridview

ex.

```
score | scoretotal
25    | 30
20    | 40
25    | 25
```

now, how can I get the total of Quiz and total of "scoretotal" or should I say, how to get the total on what only the datagridview displayed?

```
Private Sub datagrid()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sSQL = "SELECT  score as score, total as total FROM prelimquiz"
        sSQL = sSQL & " where username like '%" & Administrator.lblusername.Text & "%' and studentid like '%" & Me.Label25.Text & "%'"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why this multiplication *score as score, total as total* ?

Answer (score 1):

By linq:

```
 Dim dtAsEnum = dt.AsEnumerable
 Dim ScoreResult = dtAsEnum.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("score"))
 Dim TotalResult = dtAsEnum.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("total"))
```

Comment: How will i display this to textbox1 and textbox2?

Comment: textbox1.Text = ScoreResult and textbox2.Text = TotalResult

Comment: @lomed I think you meant `textbox1.Text = ScoreResult.ToString()` etc.