# How to display total sum from database to textboxes?

Tags: vb.net

Guys How can I display the sum from database to textbox1 and textbox2?

```
Private Sub totalquiz()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
       sSQL = "Select sum(quiz) as score,sum(total) as total FROM prelimquiz  where [username]='ad' And studentID='1111111'"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
    textbox1.Text =dt.Rows[2].ToString()
textbox2.text =dt.rows[3].ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I dont know how to correctly get the total sum and display to textboxes.

Comment: Can you please explain the differences between this question, the one you posted 1 hour ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206718/how-to-display-the-total-sum-to-textbox) and the other one you posted 2 hours ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206279/how-can-i-get-the-total-or-sum-up-my-database-access)? You should ask a new question per problem, but not many questions for the same thing. Think carefully about what you want and just focus on one question. Your first question got an answer, why don't you improve this question, perhaps the answerer can solve it for you?

Comment: sorry i'll restrain my related question, since i don't have any background of vb.net like how to get sSQL = "Select sum(quiz) as score,sum(total) as total FROM prelimquiz  where [username]='ad' And studentID='1111111'"
 and display to textboxes.
this is the only problem left and needed to pass tomorrow. i'm trying to understand this language

Comment: Asking the same question over and over will not help you understand/solve the problem. Writing a proper question and helping the eventual helpers to understand your problem better, would certainly do so. As a rough preliminary idea, you have to understand that one thing is the VB.NET code and other thing is the SQL part (managed by your DB). The variable sSQL, for VB.NET is a mere string; for SQL has certain orders. You can send a basic query and maximise the returned information via VB.NET (loops, LINQ, DataTable object, etc.); or send a more complex query and let SQL to take care of things.

Comment: Also remember that SO expects a minimal understanding from you before asking a question. If you don't have this minimal understanding, you should perform some research to make your ideas clearer before asking. In any case, you should post clearly what you don't understand, what you have tried and the exact constraints; all this ONCE (but you can edit/upgrade this one attempt as many times as you wish).

Answer (score 0):

your query will return only one record containing the sum you wanted

to access it simply do the following

```
dt.Rows[0]["score"].ToString();
dt.Rows[0]["total"].ToString();
```

hope it will help you
regards